# Realm React-Native: Access same realm from JS(react native code) and android(java)

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, realm

I have a use case where i am receiving some data in android code(native). I want to insert this data into the same realm which is opened or made by my react code.

Or write in the same realm. How can I achieve this? All the help is appreciated.
P.S. I know I can somehow make a native module and send data back to my JS and perform operations there.. but I am not sure it will happen if my app is not in foreground.

Right now I am running a service in background which will receive data and save it in realm.

Any way I can do this ??

Comment: Even now, Realm React-Native and Realm Java's version releases don't seem to have matching core versions, so not at the moment, I think. If Realm-JS picks up the slack a bit, then it'll be possible

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for your insight. Still I have to achieve this, so it would be really great if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't really hang out on the Realm-JS issues, but the only thing I can think of is nagging them a bit to release a Realm-JS for react native with core 2.6.1 and sync 1.6.0, so I posted an issue https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/984 -- but you should generally make sure you know where your migrations happen for the Realm file.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you so much for looking into it. I am given to understand that migration happens only when the schema is changed right ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It would be great if you could elaborate a bit more on core and sync or direct me to somewhere where i could read it.

Comment: According to https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/984#issuecomment-297716769 the only way to get the same core and sync and object-store versions reliably for your app is if you build Realm-JS and Realm-Java from scratch and use them in your application like that.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that is quite tedious. Thank you anyways, I am thinking of switching to this -> https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage
it might solve this

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I just want to use Realm both on native and react native code correct?

If so, it should be as simple as initialising the Realms on both codes (with the same path), and write/query normally. I did this and it worked.

Comment: That's really great. Are you able to access the same data from both interfaces (JS and java) ? For ex. if the JS code makes some changes in the underlying realm, are you able to get those changes from the native(Java) side ?
Thanks for help. @ramon

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement and tried accessing the same file from android and react-native which breaks my application. I changed to pathfile on one side to proof its pathfile related.

It would be great, if someone from the realm team can confirm this is/should work or not and what I should do to fix this issue. I assume more users will use services in android and need to access the data in react-native.

versions js:
"realm": "^2.21.0",
"react-native": "0.57.7",

version android:
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
minSdkVersion = 26